# What is the best way to create shared message stream for Python scripts?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, subprocess, multiprocessing

**What I want to do:** I need a simple message stream, so some scripts can send results there and another script can take results and do some work asynchronously.

**Main problem:** I want to see what's happening, so if something breaks - I can fix it quickly. I tried to use Celery+RabbitMQ (can see workers with args, using Flower, but scheduling too complicated) and multiprocessing.Queue (simple, but can't see workers with args).

---

**What I've done:** I tried to build something similar, using MongoDB capped collection and run Popen with multiple processes, to react. Some scripts write smth to the collection, the script below monitors it and if some condition is met - run another script.

**Main problem:** subprocess.Popen() usage from inside multiprocessing.Process() looks unnatural (still does the work), so I'm trying to find better or/and more stable solution :)

---

Listener script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, CursorType
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess

def worker_email(keyword):
     subprocess.Popen(["python", "worker_email.py", str(keyword)])

def worker_checker(keyword):
     subprocess.Popen(["python", "worker_checker.py", str(keyword)])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #DB connect
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.admetric
    coll = db.my_collection
    cursor = coll.find(cursor_type = CursorType.TAILABLE_AWAIT)

    #Script start UTC time
    utc_run = datetime.utcnow()

    while cursor.alive:
        try:
            doc = cursor.next()
            #Print doc name/args to see in command line, while Listener runs
            print(doc)
            #Filter docs without 'created' data
            if 'created' in doc.keys():
                #Ignore docs older than script
                if doc['created'] > utc_run:
                    #Filter docs without 'type' data
                    if 'type' in doc.keys():
                        #Check type
                        if doc['type'] == 'send_email':
                            #Create process and run external script
                            p = Process(target=worker_email, args=(doc['message'],))
                            p.start()
                            p.join()
                        #Check type
                        elif doc['type'] == 'check_data':
                            #Create process and run external script
                            p = Process(target=worker_checker, args=(doc['message'],))
                            p.start()
                            p.join()
        except StopIteration:
            sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess` to run a Python script? Just run the Python code via `multiprocessing.Process`.

Comment: @noxdafox I have like 500-600 lines of code in each external file, so subprocess looks cleaner than from import *. I'm scared of trashing main script namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have control over the `worker_email` and `worker_checker` logic, you don't need to execute the in a separate interpreter.

Just expose an entry point in the two modules and run them via `multiprocessing.Process`.

worker_email.py

```
def email_job(message):
    # start processing the message here
```

worker_checker.py

```
def check_job(message):
    # start checking the message here
```

listener_script.py

```
# you are not going to pollute the listener namespace
# as the only names you import are the entry points of the scripts
# therefore, encapsulation is preserved
from worker_email import email_job
from worker_checker import check_job

email_process = Process(target=email_job, args=[message])
check_process = Process(target=check_job, args=[message])
```

If you cannot expose an entry point from the worker modules then just run `subprocess.Popen`. You have no benefit in wrapping them within a `Process`.

Comment: 1. I tried to use import, still worker files include 500-600 lines of code each and many functions, so I decided using Popen() is cleaner than from import * :) Is it?
---
2. Wrapping them within a Process allows to use multiple cores, I need to run 50-100 workers every 5-10 seconds.

Comment: 1. No, it is not cleaner. Importing just the function you need is much better than launching a totally separate Python interpreter. Check the comment in my code example. 2. `subprocess.Popen` already runs the logic in a new process. If you wrap it within a process you end up with two processes of which one is waiting for the other. There is no benefit whatsoever :)